# How can I draw on a canvas larger than my screen's dimensions?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I'm creating an Android application that allows users to draw on a surface. Unfortunately, the maximum image size of the canvas in my application is 1000 x 1500 pixels on my phone, and scales depending on the device dimensions but no larger.

My goal is to allow the user to draw in the app, but for the drawing to be contained in various larger canvases, such as for example one that is 4032 x 3264 pixels. How can I override the maximum canvas dimensions of the device for the bitmap I want to draw on? Should the drawing process occur on the server, and should the rendered image be displayed on the client in real time? Or can I somehow make the canvas larger than the screen, initialize a fully zoomed out view of the image and allow the user to scroll around it, zoom in/zoom out, etc. while also being able to draw?

I've posted a public gist to the class I've created here for context:

https://gist.github.com/santafebound/57f45c636e69c53b1df79302b8946099

Simply changing the size of generated image results in the following error:

```
09-17 11:29:03.718 4490-4490/com.elgami.customizer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.elgami.customizer, PID: 4490
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 52641804 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 44MB until OOM
         at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
         at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
         at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:831)
         at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
         at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:775)
         at com.elgami.customizer.MainActivity.SetupTemplate(MainActivity.java:451)
         at com.elgami.customizer.MainActivity.SetupTemplate(MainActivity.java:434)
         at com.elgami.customizer.MainActivity$1.onPageScrollStateChanged(MainActivity.java:289)
         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnScrollStateChanged(ViewPager.java:1944)
         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setScrollState(ViewPager.java:497)
         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2119)
         at com.elgami.views.ExtendedViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ExtendedViewPager.java:44)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2108)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
         at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2771)
         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
         at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9520)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
         at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
         at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at andr
```

Comment: try this library. it might be helpful. https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: Its just matter of Math. Being said get the Device res then do some percentage base computation.

Answer (score -1):

Try subclassing the Canvas and using a fixed MeasureSpec to lock in the size you want:

```
private static final int fixedWidthMeasureSpec
        = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(4032, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

private static final int fixedHeightMeasureSpec
        = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(3264, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

// ...

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMS, int heightMS) {
    super.onMeasure(fixedWidthMeasureSpec, fixedHeightMeasureSpec);
}
```